# box2d, setTransform and collisions

Tags: box2d, transform, libgdx, collision

I'm using body.setTransform to move some of my objects around.
I know it's bad, but it is just the way it needs to be in my case -
bodies follow certain paths. When such a body is hit by a bullet
it stops moving on the path (body.setTransform() is no longer called)
and it lets physics act.

The problem is that sometimes the body freaks out - it seems like the
contact force etc. is applied to different body values (coordinates etc).
As a result it starts spinning and flies throw other bodies.

It is clearly the problem with body.setTransform(), because when I turn
moving on path off all physics is fine. My google findings also confirm that
body.setTransform() may screw up physics.

I was trying to set all velocities to 0 after a contact. That cancels the contact
impact and the body doesn't move. But its 'physic data' seems to be still corrupted -
it doesn't act right when it is hit with something afterwards.

Is there any way to 'reset' a body that was tempered with using body.setTransform()
so that it acts properly again?

Comment: The body itself was not freaking out. It was the renderer that was not rendering it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `b2MouseJoint` to move the body along the path and preserve correct physical behaviour.

Comment: I never used it but it could be worth a try. I just have one more question. The path is used to avoid STATIC obstacles and it works perfectly with body.setTransform(). There are also DYNAMIC obstacles which the body may hit. Even if the body hits a DYNAMIC obstacle it doesn't affect it staying on path which is good. It just pushes the DYNAMIC obstacle and still avoids the STATIC one. If I use the MouseJoint in such a situation will the body path be affected when it hits a dynamic obstacle? Is this joint strong enough to make the body stay on path?

Comment: @Dzik: all bodies will affect it. mouse joint is just a b2DistanceJoint as I know - so i would just try to play with parameters, but I think it will be strong enough. In order to avoid collisions with static bodies you can use contact filtering (b2Filter)